# force element to display outside of overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

This is probably attempting the impossible, but I would like to display an element outside of an element that is `overflow: hidden`. I know that makes no sense and things are working as they should, but just wanted to double check to see if there is a way.

Best described with this code:

```css
.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
}

.show-up {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="show-up">this needs to show up ALL 300 pixels high of it</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUNNf/4/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? what is the overflow:hidden; there for?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think this is actually possible. Maybe you can try setting the inner element to "position: absolute;". I doubt that'll work though. Why must the outter element be overflow hidden?

Comment: This situation can be good for adding element for tooltip, that should be visible only on hovering the parent. And you want the tooltip to go outside the overflow:hidden element.

Comment: [This article](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `overflow:hidden` definition will hide anything inside that element that extends beyond its bounds.

Depending on your specific application, you may be able to use a structure like this:

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
}
.show-up {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="show-up">this needs to show up ALL 300 pixels high of it</div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUNNf/11/)

Answer (score 23):

Make an additional outer div with position relative and set the absolute position of the div you want to move outside of the overflow hidden div.

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.overflow-hid-div{
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-left:50px;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
}
.inner{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:green;
  position: absolute;
  left:25px;
  top:25px;

}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='overflow-hid-div'>
        <div class='inner'>
            sup!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/ysgrevoh/1/

Answer (score 23):

I was struggling for ages with this for a tooltip. My containing element is `overflow: hidden` and add I can't add extra wrapper `divs` because it causes some weird bug with flexbox and `ResizeObserver`. As far as I know there is no way for a `position: absolute` element to escape a parent that is *both* `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`.

However I discovered that **`position: fixed` elements aren't clipped by `overflow: hidden` at all**, and it's actually easier to use `position: fixed` in my case. Might be an option for some.

Comment: Saved my day ! Had the same problem for a date-picker inside a table (which had an `overflow: auto`). I still don't understand why `position: fixed` still move the element on scroll (as if it was not fixed), but perfect for me !

Comment: Can you make some live example? It seems that it's not working for me..

Comment: I am facing a similar issue for tooltip and have created a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68456708/display-element-over-another-div-with-hidden-overflow Can you please answer it or maybe post a link to the solution that worked for you?

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it required no additional changes to my layout and worked perfectly.

Comment: you mean `overflow: hidden`, right? there's no overlay..

Comment: Yeah I think so.

Answer (score 6):

please check the following fiddle I created:
http://jsfiddle.net/NUNNf/12/

You should add an external container like such:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="show-up">this needs to show up ALL 300 pixels high of it</div>
</div>
```

and then add the elements inside.

Styling:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
}

.container {
    position:relative;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
}

.show-up{
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: That looks great, but your fiddle doesn't reflect your code show here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust how content overflows in a container without hiding it, you can use the `overflow` CSS property with a value other than "hidden." There are three main values you can use:

1. `overflow: visible;`: This is the default value, and it allows content to overflow the container without any clipping. It will be visible outside the container, potentially overlapping other elements.

```css
.container {
  [overflow: visible;][1]
}
```

2. `overflow: scroll;`: This value adds both horizontal and vertical scrollbars to the container if the content overflows. Users can scroll to view the hidden content.

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

3. `overflow: auto;`: This value only adds scrollbars if the content exceeds the container's dimensions. If there's no overflow, no scrollbars will be displayed.

```css
.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's a simple example [demonstrating the use of these overflow properties:](https://w3axis.com/)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: scroll; /* Change this to visible or auto to see the different behaviors */
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, if you set `overflow: scroll;`, scrollbars will appear when the content exceeds the container's dimensions. If you set `overflow: visible;`, the overflowing content will be visible outside the container. If you set `overflow: auto;`, scrollbars will appear only when the content overflows.