# Need image to cross the container height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `img` inside a `div` container which has some background color. I want the image to overlay on top of the div container and cross it's height beyond the div's height, without any scroll bars.

A fiddle related to this http://jsfiddle.net/mLtfcm6n/2/
Fiddle code:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/prettyoffice9/256/triangle.png"></img>
</div>
.container {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image {
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    height:256px;
}
```

I can't set `overflow-y` to hidden and `overflow-x` has to be hidden

The end result should be like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLtfcm6n/3/
CSS for it is(only change is removal of `overflow` property):

```
.container {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;

}

.image {
    position:absolute;
    left:40px;
    height:256px;
}
```

Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [force element to display outside of overflow hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328947/force-element-to-display-outside-of-overflow-hidden)

Comment: why do you not want to use `overflow:visible`

Comment: `overflow:visible` doesn't work. The duplicate does give much insight into what a workable way around could be

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.image {
    position:fixed;
    left:40px;
    height:256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/prettyoffice9/256/triangle.png"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image to be positioned relative to the parent/container.. making `position:fixed;` will make the image stay on the same place