# Show positioned div outside of overflow hidden grandparent

Tags: css

I am in the middle of publishing a library which other people are going to use. But I can't solve this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Reproduction:**

1. Go to https://goodmite.github.io/designer/
2. Click on the blue button.

[image]

**Problem:**

I have been trying to show a popover over a button. Popover is bigged than one of its grandparent which is overflow hidden. Therefore it appears clipped. I have looked into SO posts like the one here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328947/force-element-to-display-outside-of-overflowhidden) but they dont fit my needs.

Comment: Can't you change the pop-up div positioned in html so that it wont be child to div with `overflow: hidden` but next to it?  with that it won't be affected with `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Unfortunately no. Buttons (and hence popovers) are parent of carousal, which must have overflow: hidden.

Comment: It would work if any ancestor **up to and including that grandparent** is *not positioned*.

Comment: @connexo you can see i can't do that because button must be positioned relative

Comment: Then there is no solution given your current restrictions.

Comment: @connexo thanks...i used popper.js