# How to force a element to display outside of a div with overflow:hidden and postion: fixed?

Tags: html, css

I want to know that, how can I display an element/div outside of a div(position: fixed and overflow: hidden) and `.show-up{position: absolute;}`? **Run Snippet**

```css
.container {
    position:fixed;  
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-up {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="show-up">
    this needs to show up ALL 300 pixels high of it
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [force element to display outside of overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328947/force-element-to-display-outside-of-overflowhidden)

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `position:fixed` on that element:

```css
.container {
    position:fixed;  
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-up {
    position:fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;    
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="show-up">
    this needs to show up ALL 300 pixels high of it
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to add `position: fixed` to inner div. It can be `position: absolute`.

Comment: `position:fixed` solves your problem - what  you want cannot be done using `position:absolute`. So, essentially the answer is correct, even if it doesn't fit your context. What are you trying to achieve anyway? You can probably use `fixed` to 'fake' absolute positioning